# attempting to upload file with boto3 from same script it was created in but getting error: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, boto3

here is the code

```
with open('browse_venues_current_content.json', 'w') as my_file:
  json.dump(endproduct, my_file)

 import boto3
 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
 result = s3.meta.client.upload_file('my_file', 'shofi-stuff', 'browse_venues_current_content.json')
 print(result)
```

here is the error:

```
 line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'my_file'
```

what should I be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `browse_venues_current_content.json` not `"my_file"`:

```
endproduct = [1,2,3]

with open('browse_venues_current_content.json', 'w') as my_file:
    json.dump(endproduct, my_file)


s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

result = s3.meta.client.upload_file(
        'browse_venues_current_content.json', 
        'shofi-stuff', 
        'browse_venues_current_content.json')

print(result)
```

Comment: so with your answer I am getting teh following error `raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Input <_io.TextIOWrapper name='browse_venues_current_content.json' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> of type: <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'> is not supported.` Are you famliar with this?

Comment: @ChristopherJakob Seems you are opening the file in write mode (`mode='w' `), which is your original question, not in my answer.

Comment: so i Got another error `unsupportedOperation: write` as well I saw you commented out my json.dump. I don't understand, how do I write my data to the file without supplying it the data I want to write to it. Is there something I am not seeing?

Comment: @ChristopherJakob I had to comment out your json dump as I don't know what `endproduct` is. My understanding is that `browse_venues_current_content.json` file exists, you open it and upload to s3? Your intention is different?

Comment: correct my intention is different. The desire is to create a file called `browse_venues_current_content_.json` from the json array I have created which is stored in the variable `endproduct` then it is upload the new file object called `my_file` to s3

Comment: @ChristopherJakob `upload_file` is correct then.

Comment: looks like this may have worked I have a error which is unrelated and that I know how to fix. Will update you. But thank you for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

looks like this is my winner

The upload_fileobj method accepts a readable file-like object. The file object must be opened in binary mode, not text mode.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open("FILE_NAME", "rb") as f:
    s3.upload_fileobj(f, "BUCKET_NAME", "OBJECT_NAME")
```

The upload_file and upload_fileobj methods are provided by the S3 Client, Bucket, and Object classes. The method functionality provided by each class is identical. No benefits are gained by calling one class's method over another's. Use whichever class is most convenient.